# Force specific format for date or time in datagridview no matter what user entry format it is

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-4.0

I have only time column within datagridview I have set the Time column format as `t` in it but I am getting error when adding it is value to the database using parameterized query that says

> SqlDbType.Time overflow.  Value '955.00:00:00' is out of range.  Must
>   be between 00:00:00.0000000 and 23:59:59.9999999.

here is the command line that bind the parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@START_TIME", SqlDbType.Time)).Value = DGV_PatientSessions.CurrentRow.Cells["DGV_PatientSessions_StartTime"].Value;
```

because when users enter a date in random format I need to know how to force 
or overwrite the entered format to a specific format to avoid issues like this

or maybe alter user with a massage to use specific format instead of throwing an exception

Comment: `DateTime` either in .NET or SQL Server has *no* format. It's a binary value. Configure your *grid* to display dates using specific formats

Comment: As for this specific error, it has nothing to do with formats. A `time` field contains the time of day, not an interval. It *can't* contain `'955.00:00:00`. You'll have to add validations to your code to ensure the grid or datatable don't contain invalid values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have no issue on reading dates from sql server to gridview my issue is when user enter  a value in the cell of datagridview and then bind that value to parameter to store it in database

Comment: BTW the correct type for a `time` field is `TimeSpan`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will try it TimeSpan maybe will help

Comment: as I said, you'll have to validate the values in your client code. Ensure the type is a timespan, add constraints that *don't* allow the user to enter values greater than a single day. Use a time picker control. This can't be fixed when you call the stored procedure

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please would mind to show me an example for validation ?

Comment: for what type of application? Winforms, WPF, Webforms, ASP.NET MVC? Validation is described on all tutorials. In the worst case you can just check the contents of `DGV_PatientSessions.CurrentRow.Cells["DGV_PatientSessions_StartTime"].Value` and refuse to store the data if the value is greater or equal to 24 hours

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Winforms application

Comment: This is described in the documentation extensively, eg [How to: Validate Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-validate-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control), [Walkthrough: Validating Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-validating-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you might validate the value of that cell before attempting to assign it to the SQL parameter:

```
DateTime temp;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(DGV_PatientSessions.CurrentRow.Cells["DGV_PatientSessions_StartTime"].Value, out temp)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Start time is not a valid time");
    return;
}
```

If it gets past this check, you can assign it to the parameter.

Comment: The value is a DateTime already, or something that succesfully parses to a value greater than 24 hours